# Using Zod with Recursive types and infer them properly

Tags: typescript, zod

I have schemas like so:

```
export const barSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  foo: z.object(fooSchema),
});

export const fooSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  bar: z.object(barSchema),
});

export type BarType = z.infer<typeof barSchema>;
```

However `barSchema` gives me the typescript error:

```
'barSchema' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
```

I really want to use the ability to infer types. How can I do that and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think what you're asking for is possible if the Zod documentation is to be believed.

> You can define a recursive schema in Zod, but because of a limitation of TypeScript, their type **can't be statically inferred**. Instead you'll need to define the type definition manually, and provide it to Zod as a "type hint".

[Zod Docs](https://zod.dev/?id=recursive-types)